# Read serial port in Java

Tags: java

I am looking for a library to read  a serial signal with 1 MHz baud rate in Java that no have specific protocol so I decided to read this signal bit by bit.

How do I do that and what library is designed for this?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264277/java-serial-communication-on-windows

Comment: On which OS do you want the library to work?

Comment: @Thomas Weller Java is OS independant programming language.

Comment: @convert: Java, yes, but a library needn't be OS independent. It might e.g. use [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to get the desired result.

Comment: @Thomas Weller But even JNI APIs are cros platform. Or you tallking about writing own JNI solution?

Comment: @convert: if I implement something in C or C++ and I call a Windows API for opening and closing Serial ports, maybe the JNI API is cross platform, but the implementation isn't.

Comment: @Thomas Weller Yes it´s right, but I personally don´t know any Java API having implementation only for a single OS. For example the solution from my answer is OS independant.

Answer (score 1):

Not shure but [jSerialComm](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) could be the API you are searching.